# Durandal - View Not Found. Searched for "/" on intermittent

Tags: durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

I wonder if anyone has had a similar problem with Durandal.js.

I am getting an intermittent "View Not Found. Searched for" error, which is hard to replicate as only happens very occasionally.

It appears to spawn from the file viewEngine.js when the createView function is unable to locate the view.  However the view is present and works 99% of the time.

Anyone had similar issues, or know of a way in which I can track down and fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: What browsers are you experiencing this issue in?

Comment: Check if it relates to this: https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/issues/589

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dziamid. This happens in chrome too, so I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: I am having the same issue exactly as you describe and have yet to find a cause.

Comment: It turns out that it was require.js causing the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case it was require.js causing the problem.

In main.js add the following and add the waitSeconds parameter:

```
require.config({
    waitSeconds : 0
});
```

This prevents require.js from timing out when trying to load files.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-waitSeconds